# TPROXY for IPV6

Tags: ipv6, transparentproxy

I have my own NAT modules for IPV6.I need TPROXY support.Is there any patch available for download?I am using the 2.6.32-71 kernel.

Answer (score 2):

IPv6 for tproxy was added to 2.6.37.

Comment: Also does tproxy support sctp and icmp?It seems to allow only tcp and udp

Comment: Only TCP, UDP for now. If you need other protocols, please contact the netfilter-dev mailing list to bring your request to attention.

Comment: tproxy requires changes in the tcp/udp layer, and backporting that to an earlier kernel version is something I prefer not having to do over such large distances (37->32). I was sufficiently busy with forward porting (which I consider easier than backwards) tproxy2, when that still was a patch a handful of years ago.  I guess old-kernels-at-release-time is the poison you get with certain distros.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a RedHat kernel IPv6 TProxy support was backported into RHEL6.1

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=591335

http://rhn.redhat.com/errata/RHSA-2011-0542.html

Comment: Is this available in CentOS as well?